# Beamer copenhagen theme banner height

Tags: beamer, height

I'm using beamer with Copenhagen theme. I want to use a logo in the right-most corner of all slides. I achieved this using `textblock` and `addtobeamertemplate` facilities.

My question is, when I add more sections to my presentation, the banner height increases. When the banner heights increases, I want my logo gets bigger too. So, I need to know the `height` (see added image) programmatically.

Is that possible?

[image: First slide]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that helps other to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for this particular case. It completely redefines the headline to achieve the wanted effect. The headline is taken from the `split` outer theme. Note that subsections are not included, as your image shows, although they can be added with little effort.

Redefined header (to be inserted in the preamble):

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.125ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\hfill \includegraphics[height=0.8\@tempdimb]{logo.jpeg} \hspace{1mm}~\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
```

The height of the header is calculated from the total number of sections and stored in `\@tempdimb`. This height is used throughout the definition of the headline. In the code above the logo is included taking 80% of the height of the headline, so it will be automatically resized according to the total number of sections.

Example renderings

- Two sections:
  [image]
- Five sections:
  [image: image5]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access the height via `\headheight`, so to scale your logo:

```
\includegraphics[height=\headheight]{example-image}
```